# parsing table data

Tags: java, parsing

I have a database connected java file where I have retrieved the table data .

Now, I have to parse the table data into another file where I have to take only few datas.

Can anyone help me with this ??

Comment: I hope when you say Java file, you meant Java Class.

Comment: You are wanting to make a subset of a list? Can you paste some relevant code snippet?

Answer (score 0):

Just use a WHERE clause in your SQL query, and write the latter file from these results.